# Serving AdMob through DFP SB

Tags: admob, google-dfp

I'd like to server ads from my Admob account through DFP SB in my mobile application. DFP works, I can serve image ads. When I am trying to add Admob ad unit, I get error.

My AdMob ad unit is: `ca-app-pub-2691xxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyyy`

Then, when creating AdMob ad unit in DFP, I need to input Publisher Id and Additional parameters. So as Publisher ID I have `"yyyyyyyyyy"` and as Additional parameters I have `"client=ca-app-pub-2691xxxxxxxxxxxx"`.

Still, even though I do as described in guides, I get error. What I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I think you might have the publisher id and additional params around the wrong nway.

Comment: I have tried different options, typing them other way round, but it didn't help. There might be some hidden issue, since Admob was changed to a new version recently.

Comment: You needd to post a lot more info. Starting with the error you are getting, and then the code you are using.

Comment: The error I'm getting is in Polish, but it is something like this:
"Error occurred: We couldn't connect the ad with this element of order."

The code I am using is the one I wrote above. And I've tried it other way round as well. I'm doing everything as in the guide here: https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1209767?hl=en